# How to enforce promise in array loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise

I'm trying to get the basics of how to implement promises and Promise.All within a given array loop, for example, from a firebase query, which can perform any number of actions within the loop, and then I have access to the results later. I can't seem to get the correct syntax, logic . below is a sample method in which I'd like to delay insert some items into an array and then have access to the array after the loop for processing.

I've researched different methods on Stackoverfllow. Some assign a promises = the snap.forEach loop and then somehow resolve this after completion. Others are creating a promise inside the loop. In my example below, I'm just using the settimeout to delay/create an async process.

```
        testfirebaseData = () => {

        let channels =[];
        var promises=[];
         firebase.database().ref('challengeResponses').child(day).once('value', snap => {

          snap.forEach(channelChild => {

                promises.push(new Promise((resolve) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                    channels.push(channelChild.key);
                    resolve(channels)
                   },1000)
                })
                )

             })             
        }).then (() => {
         Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
            console.log(channels[0])
        })

       }


    }
```

I would expect the output of the above to show the first element in the "channels" array, but it's always coming back with "undefined"..as I clearly am not processing the promises correctly. What am i missing?

Comment: Could you share a quick example? I've tried setting promises = fiirebase.database() ...but couldn't get that to work either. Do I need to resolve in the call back?

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample example using your code style. Instead of objects within the array I've put numbers;

https://jsfiddle.net/th3vecmg/4/

```
 var promises = [];
 let channels =[];

 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach((elm, i) => {

   promises.push(new Promise((resolve) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
      channels.push(elm)
       resolve(elm);
     },  1000)
   }))

 });
 console.log(channels[0]) // gives undefined
 Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
   console.log(channels[0]) // gives 1
 })
```

You should not be getting undefined inside the **then** because it's waiting for the promise to execute. You will only get undefined it you are trying to display the result outside the **then** scope

The code doesn't make really sense since you are displaying a global variable inside the then rather then relying on the output of the promise

If you want to delay execution by 1 then do some multiplication in the timeArgument of the setTimeout...

Comment: Stange, i copy/pasted your code and tried it...sometimes the result is 1, other times the result is 5? Not sure why it wouldn't be consistent? Even more important, I implemented the same logic in my code (keeping my firebase query/loop foreach) and it doesn't work...always returns "undedfined" even when putting it inside the then() bloc, I will update my question to include the exact code I'm trying.

Comment: Check the fiddle example if you wish, it always returns the first element but I guess you've solved you problem by now...

Answer (score 0):

Your `new Promise(...)` should wrap the firebase call as that is the async operation.  And not be in the callback. There is no async operations going on inside the callback just plain array push which is a sync op

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve)=>{
   firebase.database().ref('challengeResponses').child(day).once('value', snap => {
     var channels=[];
     snap.forEach(channelChild => {
       channels.push(channelChild.key);
     });
     resolve(channels);
   });
});

promise.then((channels)=>{
    console.log(channels);
});
```

If you want a delay on the whole operation:

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve)=>{
   firebase.database().ref('challengeResponses').child(day).once('value', snap => {
     var channels=[];
     setTimeout(()=>{
       snap.forEach(channelChild => {
         channels.push(channelChild.key);
       });
       resolve(channels);
     },1000);
   });
});
```

To simulate nested async operations you would add the promises to an array like you were but resolve `Promises.all()` in the outer promise and resolve your data in the inner promises:

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve)=>{
   firebase.database().ref('challengeResponses').child(day).once('value', snap => {
      var snapPromises=[];
      snap.forEach(channelChild => {
         snapPromises.push(new Promise((snapresolve)=>{
           setTimeout(()=>{
             snapresolve(channelChild.key);
           },1000)
         });
      });
      resolve(Promise.all(snapPromises));         
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but I wanted to use the settimeout to delay the processing to see what happens. if you use your code, but put the array push inside a settimeout like this setTimeout(() => {
                               channels.push(channelChild.key)
                           }, 1000); ...it comes back with "undefined". Why?

Comment: Because setTimeout is an async operation too the code inside it isnt going to run before the original promise finishes. If you want to delay the whole operation put the forEach() / resolve calls inside a setTimeout. If you want a delay for each iteration of the forEach you would need to change your code around as forEach doesnt use or wait for promises

Comment: couldn't the settimeout be put into a promise? At which point, we'd collect all those p;romises and use Promise.All(promises) to then do the console.log? I was trying to use settimeout to simulate other async logic that would be in the foreach loop

Comment: See latest edit to see simulating nested async operations

Comment: thanks, that's what i was looking for. The firebase call returns a promise already, so I just needed to add a .then() to this logic and then call the Promise.all(). Appreciate the feedback!